# How to get children and id in jQuery Nestable plugin after drag and drop item and update in database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-plugins

I'm using ***jQuery Nestable plugin*** to create a menu editor for a website.
I've tried to get item **ID** and **Children** after user clicks on menu items and change their position.

**Issue**: I don't know how to get ID and Children and update into database.

Here is ***jQuery Nestable plugin***

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var updateOutput = function (e) {
            var list = e.length ? e : $(e.target), output = list.data('output');
            if (window.JSON) {output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));//, null, 2));
            } else {
                output.val('JSON browser support required for this demo.');
            }
        console.log(list.nestable('serialize'));
        console.log(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));
        };
        $('#nestable').nestable({
            group: 1,
            maxDepth: 7,
        }).on('change', updateOutput);
        updateOutput($('#nestable').data('output', $('#nestable-output')));
    });
</script>
```

Here is HTML for menus

```
<div class="cf nestable-lists">
    <div class="dd" id="nestable">
        <ol class="dd-list">
            <li class="dd-item" data-id="1"> <div class="dd-handle">Item 1 when parent == 0</div> </li>
            <li class="dd-item" data-id="44"> <div class="dd-handle"> Item 2 when this parent_id == its id </div>
                <ol class="dd-list">
                    <li class="dd-item" data-id="3"><div class="dd-handle">Item 3</div></li>
                    <li class="dd-item" data-id="4"><div class="dd-handle">Item 3</div></li>
                    <li class="dd-item" data-id="5"><div class="dd-handle">Item 3</div></li>
                    <li class="dd-item" data-id="6"><div class="dd-handle">Item 3</div></li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result on ***Console***

```
[{"id":1},{"id":44,"children":[{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5},{"id":6}]}]
```

***Edition***

In my structure I want to update menus when **Parent_id** **==** **id** where menus **id** and create level of menus item bu number of **M_order**. But I don't know to create this structure.

And here is var_dump($this->input->post('list'));

```
 1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '5' (length=1)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'children' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
```

Here is images of my **Table** structure and menus

[image]

Comment: What does your current PHP file for storing/retrieving this data from database look like? And what's the structure of the database table that holds that information? And what's the DB vendor, MSSQL, MySQL?

Comment: I don't know to do in PHP and I also how can I find Id and children and How can I update m_order when user change item position

Comment: This requirement makes your question too broad. Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, where it's expected that you try things by yourself first, and when you get stuck, you can ask specific questions. Take a look at the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page. Having said that, this looked like a bit of fun, so I went ahead and wrote a PHP script to save the ordering on each change. But it's a generic implementation, you'll probably have to tweak it to make it work for your page. I have edited my answer to include it, check it out.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To send the list to PHP, you have to change your `updateOutput` function to post the list via AJAX:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var updateOutput = function (e) {
        var list = e.length ? e : $(e.target), output = list.data('output');

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "saveList.php",
            data: {
                list: list.nestable('serialize')
            }
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("Unable to save new list order: " + errorThrown);
        });
    };

    $('#nestable').nestable({
        group: 1,
        maxDepth: 7,
    }).on('change', updateOutput);
});
</script>
```

In PHP, you will receive `$_POST['list']`, which will look as shown below. In this case, I dragged the 4th item (id 6) to the 2nd place (after id 3) on the list, so the expected order is `3, 6, 4, 5`:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 1
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 44
        [children] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [id] => 3
            )
            [1] => Array (
                [id] => 6
            )
            [2] => Array (
                [id] => 4
            )
            [3] => Array (
                [id] => 5
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Then you can just iterate over this array and update your database accordingly.

---

**Edit**: In order to save the data in PHP, you'll have to use recursion to navigate all the children arrays that might exist. I wrote a simple script that will save on every ordering change:

**index.php**

```
<?php
require "pdoConnection.php";
$list = getFullListFromDB($conn);
?>

<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dbushell/Nestable/master/jquery.nestable.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var updateOutput = function (e) {
        var list = e.length ? e : $(e.target), output = list.data('output');

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "saveList.php",
            data: {
                list: list.nestable('serialize')
            }
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("Unable to save new list order: " + errorThrown);
        });
    };

    $('#nestable').nestable({
        group: 1,
        maxDepth: 7,
    }).on('change', updateOutput);
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="cf nestable-lists">
    <div class="dd" id="nestable">
<?php displayList($list); ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php
function getFullListFromDB($conn, $parent_id = 0) {
    $sql = "
        SELECT id, parent_id, description
        FROM items 
        WHERE parent_id = :parent_id
        ORDER BY m_order
    ";

    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':parent_id', $parent_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($result as &$value) {
        $subresult = getFullListFromDB($conn, $value["id"]);

        if (count($subresult) > 0) {
            $value['children'] = $subresult;
        }
    }
    unset($value);

    return $result;
}

function displayList($list) {
?>
    <ol class="dd-list">
    <?php foreach($list as $item): ?>
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="<?php echo $item["id"]; ?>"><div class="dd-handle"><?php echo $item["description"]; ?></div>
    <?php if (array_key_exists("children", $item)): ?>
    <?php displayList($item["children"]); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
<?php
}
?>
```

**saveList.php**

```
<?php

require "pdoConnection.php";

if ($_POST) {
    saveList($conn, $_POST['list']);
    exit;
}

function saveList($conn, $list, $parent_id = 0, &$m_order = 0) {
    foreach($list as $item) {
        $m_order++;

        $sql = "
            UPDATE items
            SET 
                parent_id = :parent_id,
                m_order = :m_order
            WHERE id = :id
        ";
        $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindValue(":parent_id", $parent_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->bindValue(":id", $item["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->bindValue(":m_order", $m_order, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->execute();

        if (array_key_exists("children", $item)) {
            saveList($conn, $item["children"], $item["id"], $m_order);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**pdoConnection.php**

```
<?php
$server = "myServer"; $database = "DbName"; $username = "myself"; $password = "secret";
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$server;Database=$database", $username, $password);
?>
```

**Table definition (MSSQL)**

```
CREATE TABLE [items](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [parent_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [m_order] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_items] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT [items] ([id], [parent_id], [description], [m_order]) VALUES (1, 0, N'Item 1', 1)
INSERT [items] ([id], [parent_id], [description], [m_order]) VALUES (2, 0, N'Item 2', 2)
INSERT [items] ([id], [parent_id], [description], [m_order]) VALUES (3, 2, N'Item 3.1', 3)
INSERT [items] ([id], [parent_id], [description], [m_order]) VALUES (4, 2, N'Item 3.2', 4)
INSERT [items] ([id], [parent_id], [description], [m_order]) VALUES (5, 2, N'Item 3.3', 5)
INSERT [items] ([id], [parent_id], [description], [m_order]) VALUES (6, 2, N'Item 3.4', 6)
```

Comment: I'm so difficult to update this array in my database

Comment: What have you tried so far? Edit your question and add your current PHP script and table structure.

Comment: I'm really thanks you very much for you answer let me testing it now I will back when I ready. Thanks

Comment: Dear Sir It working now But I can't create sub level of this menus It can only level one

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. I just tested the above code again and I was able to create many levels of submenus, PHP is storing and retrieving correctly from the database. So, it must be some problem on your implementation. What you could do is to test my example as is and see it working, maybe this can help you figure out the problem on your code. If you still don't succeed, I suggest you to open a new question and explain your current problem, to not make this one too broad. This one, about getting id and children and updating into database has already been addressed.

Comment: Hi Sir,

I've already create an question Please check below link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31911187/how-to-create-sub-level-of-menus-using-jquery-nestable-plugin-with-codeigniter

Comment: Sir,
I can't find the solution now Please help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31911187/how-to-create-sub-level-of-menus-using-jquery-nestable-plugin-with-codeigniter

Comment: hey can you do it in visual studio mvc i need it please help me.

Comment: there were bugs in logic but yes idea was great and your idea help me to finish its codeigniter version. thank you