# How to create sub level of menus using jQuery Nestable plugin with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm using **jQuery Nestable plugin** with **Codeigniter3** to create 5 levels of menus for website which a good solution for user can drab and drop to change the level and position of menus items. However my below function can create only first level of menus and when I change to sub level (2,3,4,5) of menu item it won't work for me.

**Issue** I could not change menus item to another level from level one. and I couldn't reversed menus item back to **Parent** if I've been changed it to be a **children** of any **parent**. Whatever Jquery Nestable is working very will.

This below function is using to update menus item to database which depend on 
Menus column like :**id**, **Parent_id**, **m_order**.

This function will check up inside of **$List** array by **foreach** and **array_key_exists** as below description:

1. get array data from **form** using $this->get_child($this->input->post('list'));
2. Using **Foreach** and **array_key_exists** function to check any **childrent** of **$List** array and if it found any **children** it will update to database as below CI function.
3. And This **if ($parent_id != $item['id']) {...}** will not update **parent_id** for current **id** of parent.

   ```
   public function savelist() {

       if ($this->input->post('list')) {
           $this->do_update($this->input->post('list'));
       }
   }

   public function do_update($list, $parent_id = 0, &$m_order = 0) {

       foreach ($list as $item) {

           $m_order++;
           $data = array(
               'parent_id' => $parent_id,
               'm_order' => $m_order,
           );
           if ($parent_id != $item['id']) {

               $where = array('id' => $item['id']);
               var_dump($data . ':' . $where);
               $this->db->where($where);
               $this->db->update('nav', $data);
           }
           if (array_key_exists("children", $item)) {
               $this->do_update($item["children"], $item["id"], $m_order);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

This Jquery Nestable Plugin and Ajax function is using to send any form data to server.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var updateOutput = function (e) {
                var list = e.length ? e : $(e.target), output = list.data('output');
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "savelist",
                    data: {
                        list: list.nestable('serialize')
                    }, success: function (data) { //, textStatus, jqXHR
                        console.log(list.nestable('serialize'));
                    }
                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(" Unable to save new list order: " + errorThrown);
                });
            };
            $('#nestable').nestable({
                group: 1,
                maxDepth: 7,
            }).on('change', updateOutput);
        });
    </script>
```

How ever I've already create only one table to store all the menus item. and I make a conditional in **PHP** to check up **Parent** and **Children** when Menus **id** **equal** to **Parent_id**
Here is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nav` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `link` text NOT NULL,
  `show_condition` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `m_order` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `class` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `data` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `des` text NOT NULL,
  `lang` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `accord` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `footer` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `f_sta` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

The finally I got the menus editor as below image which let me change only one level os menus.

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with my question why have not any comment and answer?
Did I make something wrong?

Comment: In my opinion, your question covers too much. Try narrowing down the problem, people won't take your whole code and debug it for you, but they are willing to help you out with **specific problems**. I strongly recommend that you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to follow the advice given in there.

Comment: This is my fail I will leave job soon if I still can't do this.
Thanks for your recomment.

Comment: Check you're using a correct url in your ajax request, Try using the full url instead, If you have FireBug installed it would help debug this.

Comment: That is ok although I use base_url("savelist") it also work too, and this menu work for only level one it will not work for another level or when I drab menu item position back to parent as images

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the same requirement like yours and workout with that take a look on my code which is almost same as yours,

**Here is my Controller:**

```
public function select_menu_priority() {
        $data['product'] = $this->menu_model->select_menu_priority();

        $data['li'] = $this->generate_li($data['product']);

        $this->load->view("set_menu_priority_table", $data);
    }

function generate_li($product,$parent = NULL){

        $li = "";

        $p1 = array_filter($product, function($a)use($parent){ return $a['parent_menu_id'] == $parent; });

        foreach ($p1 as $p){

            $inner_li = "";

            $p2 = array_filter($product,function($a)use($p){ return $a['parent_menu_id'] == $p['id']; });

            if($p2){
                $inner_li = $this->generate_li($product,$p['id']);
            }

            $li .= "<li class='dd-item' data-id='".$p['id']."'><div class='dd-handle'>".$p['title']."</div>".$inner_li."</li>";

        }

        $ol = "<ol class='dd-list'>".$li."</ol>";

        return $ol;
    }
```

**View set_menu_priority_table.php:**

```
<?php
if (isset($product)) {    
    $entity = $this->input->post("entity");
    $entity = $entity['id'];
    if (count($product) > 0) {
        ?>
        <div class="row-fluid" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" tabindex="4" id="save">
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save
            </button>
            <p class="pull-right" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><?php if ($entity == "product") { ?><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="show_category" class="text-success" style="margin-right:10px;font-weight: bold;text-decoration: underline">Go to Category Priority</a><?php } ?><span class="label label-info ">Drag Menu to set Priority.</span></p>            
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="dd" id="product_list">
            <input type="hidden" id="entity_type" name="entity" value="<?php echo $entity ?>" />    
            <?php echo $li; ?>
        </div>
    <?php } else { ?>        
        <p><span class="label label-warning">No <?php echo ($entity == "product") ? "product" : "category"; ?> found.</span><?php if ($entity == "product") { ?><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="show_category" class="text-success" style="margin-left:15px;font-weight: bold;text-decoration: underline">Go to Category Priority</a><?php } ?></p>            
        <?php
    }
} else {
    ?>
    <p class="label label-info">Please select Category to Set Priority within the Category.</p>
<?php } ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#save").off("click").on("click", function() {
            var product_data = $("#product_list").nestable("serialize");
            var data = {product_data: product_data, entity: $("#entity_type").val()};
            if ($.bbq.getState("product_category") !== undefined) {
                data['product_category'] = $.bbq.getState("product_category");
            }
            ajax_call({
                url: '<?php echo site_url("admin/menu/update_menu_priority");?>',
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function() { },
                success: function(result) {
                    if (result['status'] == "success") {
                        alert("Priority Updated!");
                    } 
            });
        });
</script>
```

**For Update That Priority Add function `update_menu_priority` in Controller:**

```
public function update_menu_priority() {
            $data = $this->input->post("product_data");
            if (count($data)) {
                $update = $this->menu_model->update_priority_data($data);
                if ($update) {
                    $result['status'] = "success";
                } else {
                    $result['status'] = "error";
                }
            } else {
                $result['status'] = "error";
            }
            echo json_encode($result);

    }
```

**And at last ad model function for that `update_priority_data`:**

```
function update_priority_data($data, $parent = NULL) {
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($data as $d) {
            if (array_key_exists("children", $d)) {
                $this->update_priority_data($d['children'], $d['id']);
            }
            $update_array = array("priority" => $i, "parent_menu_id" => $parent);
            $update = $this->db->where("id", $d['id'])->update("menu", $update_array);
            $i++;
        }
        return $update;
    }
```

I hope this would be help full to you,
thanks.

Comment: Thanks I'm testing it now

Comment: you can use this code for any of the level you want,I have used this for 5 levels

Comment: I'm Not yet testing But I have to testing because now I busy with CI languages. You know I want to call data from DB and pass to languages file But I still can't now. but I will do next task with your code thnak too much

Comment: How ever do you have any toturrial for CI languages because I don't want to creae this for manual I creating a feature which can let user edit Languaged content by using Admin pges but I'm got stuck now

Comment: Dear @Sagar Naliyapara,

What is your table structure?

Comment: Hello,

I can't found your funciton in model $data['product'] = $this->menu_model->select_menu_priority();

Comment: it's a simple function that selects data from menu table `select * from menu`

Comment: In your array filter>

 $p1 = array_filter($product, function($a)use($parent) {
            return $a['parent_id'] == $parent;
        });

I got NULL and if I testing unasign $Parent not = NULL I will got error parent var

Comment: How can I get the value of $parent in array filter

Comment: it's null value for that function $parent = null

Comment: I got only this string '<ol class='dd-list'></ol>' (length=25).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87125/discussion-between-cambodia-channel-and-priyank57).

Comment: hello friends i want same thing in asp.net mvc please can you help me with this.